# How to mock a method call within a method for which i am writing junit test

Tags: java, junit

Could someone help me with mocking a method call within a method

my code is like :

```
public class Service {
    public List<Bean> Filter(Bean bean){
        List<Bean> Filtered_List = getUtilityService.getBeanList();
        //Do something
        return beanList;
    }
}
```

Now i want to write test case for Service class . How can i mock :
List Filtered_List = getUtilityService.getBeanList(); and set values in it.

Comment: I found a useful link to mock a method call , very useful. http://fruzenshtein.com/junit-and-mockito/

Answer (score 3):

The clean solution is to extract UtilityService to a field and pass a mock to the constructor.

```
public class Service {
    private UtilityService utilityService;

    public Service(UtilityService utilityService) {
       this.utilityService = utilityService;
    }

    public List<Bean> Filter(Bean bean){
        List<Bean> filteredList = utilityService.getBeanList();
        //Do something
        return beanList;
    }
}
```

You can also introduce a UtilityServiceFactory and have a utilityServiceFactory field in the Service.

```
public class Service {
    private UtilityServiceFactory utilityServiceFactory;

    public Service(UtilityServiceFactory utilityService) {
        this.utilityServiceFactory = utilityServiceFactory;
    }

    public List<Bean> Filter(Bean bean){
        List<Bean> filteredList = utilityService.create().getBeanList();
        //Do something
        return beanList;
    }
}
```

If getUtilityService is located in Service class, there is also a dirty solution: partial mock. But I do not recommend it. It's better to refactor  your code and use one of previous approaches.

EDIT:
    Constructor injection with @InjectMocks is not the best idea but here you are:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
//other imports

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {
    @Mock
    UtilityService utilityService;

    @InjectMocks
    Service service = new Service(null);

    @Test
    public void shouldFilterBeans() throws Exception {
        //given
        given(utilityService.getBeanList()).willReturn(asList(new Bean()));

        //when
        List<Bean> result = service.filter(new Bean());

        //then
        assertThat(result).hasSize(1); //probably you want to check something else
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for our reply . I followed first approach and i am getting null pointer exception when i am trying to access that method . I created InjectMocks for Service and Mock for utility service .

Comment: I've added an example with @InjectMocks

Answer (score 0):

- to test a method including its own parameter and return value, like the `Filter` method in your code, it's enough to just pass a `Bean` instance to it, and then assert the returned `List<Bean>` object equals to your expected result. generally, for this kind of method, i think it's no need to use mock frameworks.
- but if you really want to test the `getUtilityService().getBeanList()` method call, you should refactor your code:

  - addfield `UnitilityService service` and its corresponding setter method in your class `Service`
  - in your unit test code, inject a mocked service using the setter method to the object under test and given a returning value for its `getBeanList()` method, then invoke your `Filter` method, finally, verify the method call. for the detailed implementation, you can refer the answer of @woru.